# Sanitize data in Google Apps script (XSS)

Tags: google-apps-script, xss, google-apps-script-api

*The script:*
The script i'm working on is getting input from Google Forms and after some things done with the data from the form the script will build up an e-mail and send it to a user / some users.

*The problem:*
Now the problem is that if someone is putting html tags like **This is my answer** in the Google Form, the script will pick this up and put the text in bold when used in the e-mail.

*Question:*
Is there a function to use in Google Apps script to prevent this problem? The only thing i found was the encodeURI / encodeURIComponent but this function is normally used for URL's. If there is no function to use, should i build something by myself to escape the " < > " symbols.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine `putting html tags like This is my answer in the Google Form`. Can I ask you about the detail of it and the current issue of your script and your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike no problem i had the same question, it is an internal script so only script kiddies will use this. But the security team found the vulnerability in this script and they asked to fix this. One of the questions in the Google Form is: Enter your name. The name is used to make up a .html file that is used to send an e-mail. eg. Dear ${name} is used in this file. I found the function: appendUntrusted(addedContent) i hope this will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I used the function: [appendUnstrusted()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#appendUntrusted(String)) to solve this problem.

The e-mail that was made with the function : `HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)` gets adjusted after getting data from Google Forms.

To appended the data in de html file you can use `${atr}`